# scroll to top searchbarcontroller when clicked on tableview cell

Tags: ios, tableview, uinavigationitem, uisearchcontroller

searchController move to top when I write text but when I clicking tableview cell I want same behaviour.  searchController need to set top as its work on appstore app. like as shown below I tap on tableview cell so I want searchController to moves top. so what I have to write in my code.thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the `UITextField` in the `UISearchBar` become the first responder() when you tap the cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        if let searchField = searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
            searchField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
```